# Why am I having an invalid Syntax?

Tags: python, python-2.7, penetration-testing

Why am I having an invalid Syntax? Please be patient with me if it's just because of a stupid mistake.

```
import os
gateway = raw_input("What is your gateway IP: ")
target = raw_input("What is your target IP: ")
interface = raw_input("What is your network interface: ")
os.system('arpspoof -i {0} -t {1} {2} 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null &'.format(interface, gateway, target))
os.system('arpspoof -i {0} -t {1} {2} 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null &'.format(interface, target, gateway))
while True: 
    try:    
        stop_command = raw_input("If you want to exit type stop: ")
    if stop_command != "stop":
        print("You didn't type stop")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Comment: What line is the error on?  Does the code you're trying to run have those backticks at the beginning and end?  It also may be the `try:` with no `except:`

Comment: Please copy-paste the full and complete exception output into the question, as text. And add e.g. a comment on the line of code it happens.

Comment: Remove the `try` and reduce the indent of the input command.

Comment: You shouldn't have a try at all. There is no relevant exception that raw_input could raise that you want to catch.

Comment: The `continue` is useless too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `try` lacks either an `except`, or `finally` clause.

Comment: Thanks for helping I understand now, i removed the try

Answer (score 0):

you have a syntax error for try block

syntax for try is

```
    try
    .
    .
    except: #must come with try block
    .
    .
    finally: #this is optional
```

so the error free code would be

```
try:    
    stop_command = raw_input("If you want to exit type stop: ")
except:
    pass
if stop_command != "stop":
    print("You didn't type stop")
    continue
else:
    break`
```

Comment: Thanks but may I ask what does 'pass' do in this situation.

Comment: it's a null operation. Nothing will happen. more like ; in other programming languages